# How to redirect non www to www in sitecore?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7.2

Apart from installing rewrite modules is there a simple way to redirect non-www to www in Sitecore?

Any URL started with non-www for Eg: http://example.com should be redirected to http://www.example.com

Answer (score 3):

You can add custom processor to the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline if you want to keep everything in your .net code.

But still, rewrite module is one of the most popular ways of achieving what you need.

Comment: its an IIS server and am using sitecore. So the above solution wont work for me

Comment: Yep. IIS URL Rewrite module with a canonical redirect rule, specifically labeled as "Canonical domain name" in the Add Rule dialog.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of things you want to do as early as possible. On application level it will unnecessarily use resources. Try IIS or even better through DNS redirects.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
 {
    var builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url) { Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host };
    Response.StatusCode = 301;
    Response.AddHeader("Location", builder.ToString());
    Response.End();
 }
```

Comment: i would not hard-code stuff like this. It will be hard to maintain if they ever introduce sub-domains

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it would be to set the [targethostname](https://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties/targetHostName.aspx) in a [Site definition config](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx) patch file - although if you've got a single site instance of Sitecore you may just do it in the web.config.

The way to do it is to set hostname="example.com|www.example.com" and then set targethostname="www.example.com".